# R colouring boxplots within the box due to variables (stacked boxplot)

Tags: r, colors, boxplot, stacked

I am wondering how I can create a boxplots that have two different colors within the box.
For example my variable d, that I am plooting is the sum of variable b and c. So within each box the colour could indicate the proportion of the variable b and c creating d.
I hope this is understandable.

Here is my example:

```
    a<-c("A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","B","A")
    b<-c(1,2,3,4,3,4,5,6,3,4)
    c<-c(5,6,4,5,2,1,2,1,5,8)
    d<-c(6,8,7,9,5,5,7,7,8,12)
    df<-data.frame(a,b,c,d)

    boxplot(d~a)
```

Now I would like to color each box according to the variable b and c, so that the proportion is indicated.

Here is a picture that shows a plot that was made with Excel.
[example http://www.real-statistics.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/box-plot-excel.png](http://www.real-statistics.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/box-plot-excel.png)

Do you have any ideas how to achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Is the border between purple and green *also* the location of the median?

Comment: In my case it is not necessarily so, so I would have an additionaly line showing the median

Comment: This makes IMO no sense. Please read `?boxplot` and what data is shown with this plot. In your example `df` the boxplot range from 7 to 10 for `A`. What would be the part for `b` and `c`?

Comment: Thank you, of course you are right, Jimbou! I overlooked something here...I wanted to show that 75% of `d` is due to `c` and 25% of `d`is due to  `a`, which makes no sense in a boxplot.Then I probably stick to boxplotting `d` and show a bar next to each plot to indicate the proportions of `b` and `d`. Are there any other suggestions for better plotting this?

Comment: @KikiRiki And how you will calculate these ratios?

Comment: I would calculate the mean of the proportions, so for `A` we have three different values for `d=6,8,12` which are the sum of `b=1,2,4` and `c=5,6,8` . Now I would end up with 74,99% for `c`and 25,01% for `b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
# First the boxplot
n <- boxplot(d ~ a)
# check the x values for the boxes, here it is for A 0.6 and 1.4
axis(1, seq(0, 5, 0.1))

# proportions for the b values depended on a

# the mean values calculated using another approach you mentioned in the comment
ratio <- aggregate(df[ , -1], list(df$a), mean)
# get the percentages
ratio <- ratio$b/ratio$d

# your approach:
ratio <- c(by(df, INDICES = df$a, FUN = function(x) mean(x$b/x$d)))
ratio    
A         B         C 
0.2500000 0.4620040 0.7904762

# caculate the y values for the rectangles, no matter which mean-calculation method you used
low <- diff(n$stats[c(2, 4), ])*ratio
high <- diff(n$stats[c(2, 4),])*(1-ratio)

# the final plot
n <- boxplot(d ~ a)
rect(xleft = c(0.6) + seq_along(n$n)-1, xright = 1.4 + seq_along(n$n)-1, ybottom = n$stats[2, ], ytop = n$stats[2, ]+low, col = rgb(1, 1,0 ,0.4))
rect(xleft = c(0.6) + seq_along(n$n)-1, xright = 1.4 + seq_along(n$n)-1, ybottom = n$stats[4, ], ytop = n$stats[4, ]-high, col = rgb(0, 1, 1, 0.4))
```

The idea is to plot rectangles into the boxes using `rect()`. You have to provide x and y values for start and end, respectively. You can read the x-values from the boxplot easily by adding further continuous x-axis using `axis`. 
The y value is dependend on the `b` and `c` proportion compared to `d`. Thus, you calculate the ratio for one vector (here `b`) using `aggregate` or `by` and generate the `y` value within `rect()`. Finally the `rgb()` function calculates a color adding an alpha parameter for transparency.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[You can do a pie chart to show the share of vectors b and c in d (cf. image in link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltf4C.png)

The code hereunder shows how to do it:

```
c_share = sum(c)/sum(d)
b_share = sum(b)/sum(d)
mat = cbind(c_share, b_share)
pie(mat, labels=c("Share of C", "Share of B"))
```